# Accesing DOM elements with PHP Simple DOM

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I want to extract data from YMCA local schedule, table with data is under div="scheduler_here". For this project I'm using  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). But it's not showing any data.

```
<?php
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.activelifeadmin.com/newyork/websearch/public/index/weekview?sched=Group%20Exercise%20Schedule,Large%20Pool,Small%20Pool&branch_ids=38#/');

// Find the DIV tag with an id of "myId"
foreach($html->find('div[scheduler_here]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
?>
```

[Output PHP](http://serwer1478551.home.pl/jpo/RSS/new4.php)

[YMCA Website](http://www.activelifeadmin.com/newyork/websearch/public/index/weekview?sched=Group%20Exercise%20Schedule,Large%20Pool,Small%20Pool&branch_ids=38#)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get by id attribute:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=scheduler_here]') as $e)
```